# Как избежать "проскакивания" элементов при событиях mouseenter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется стандартная таблица html, нужно выделить последовательно ячейки, пока нажата кнопка мыши. Код следующий:

```
$('td').on('mousedown', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('colored');
    $('td').on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('colored');
    });
}).on('mouseup', function () {
    $('td').off('mouseover');
});
```

Все работает отлично, кроме того, что когда быстро двигаешь мышь, некоторые td не закрашиваются. Получается прямоугольник с пропусками:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно этого избежать? Какие события js лучше использовать вместо mouseenter? С mouseover тот же результат.

[Вот тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave) в разделе "Частота срабатывания" описано про такое поведение при быстром движении мыши. Но ничего не сказано, как можно это обойти.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave

Comment: См. вопрос, добавлена ссылка.

Comment: Да как обойти. Запоминать координаты срабатывания и закрашивать все, что между текущими и предыдущими координатами.

Comment: Потому что, в коде Вы используете mouseover, а не mouseenter

Comment: Mouseover или mouseenter на том же месте, потому что оба варианта пробовались.